# Visual Basic, Find and replace text

Tags: vb.net, replace, textbox

I have strings like these:

AABCAABDCEAADAAECDBAACBAA

ABCCABAADCDACADCDAABACCBA

ACCABAAAADCEAECDAAAABACCA

...

...

These lines contain only characters, not numbers.

I need to replace these strings with these form, and show the results on a textbox:

2A, 1B, 1C, 2A, 1B, 1D, 1C, 1E, 2A, 1D, 2A, 1E, 1C, 1D, 1B, 2A, 1C, 1B, 2A

1A, 1B, 2C, 1A, 1B, 2A, 1D, 1C, 1D, 1A, 1C, 1A, 1D, 1C, 1D, 2A, 1B, 1A, 2C, 1B, 1A

1A, 2C, 1A, 1B, 4A, 1D, 1C, 1E, 1A, 1E, 1C, 1D, 4A, 1B, 1A, 2C, 1A

- I should add a comma & space after every character.
- Collect the same characters and add the count at begining of every each character.

I'm a newbie at Visual Basic. I search "Find and Replace" softwares on the web before, but they didn't work for me. I also tried Notepad++ (and it's plugin "ToolBucket"). But it is not save the "find and replace" settings (only with a macro). So then, I downloaded "Visual Basic 2010 Express" from Microsoft's website. Thank you for your answer and help in advance.

Comment: I doubt anyone will do all that for you if you don't post any of your own efforts. Maybe start by splitting it using text to columns and then a COUNTIF function and a concatentation. That's just off the top.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I start to learn COUNTIF function.

Comment: Perhaps clarify your tags too.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the numbers of the repeating uppercase characters by using a capturing group and a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1` to that group.

While looping the matches, you could add those to a collection and afterwards print them using a comma and space as a separator.

Then you could add that string to the textbox.

```
([A-Z])\1*
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capturing group

  - `[A-Z]` Match a single uppercase char
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\1*` Repeat the backreference to group 1 0+ times to also get the single matches

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ugz5Nq/1) | [VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/Jcd38q)

For example:

```
Dim str As String = "ACCABAAAADCEAECDAAAABACCA"
Dim pattern As String = "([A-Z])\1*"
Dim list As New List(Of String)
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(str, pattern)
For Each m As Match In matches
    list.Add(m.Value.Length() & m.Groups(1).Value)
Next m

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list))
```

Result

> 1A, 2C, 1A, 1B, 4A, 1D, 1C, 1E, 1A, 1E, 1C, 1D, 4A, 1B, 1A, 2C, 1A

Comment: The pattern is wrong in the code, should be `(([A-Z])\1*)`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ You are right, I forgot to update it. I have added the code from the demo. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

A way with Regex =>

```
Dim re As Regex = New Regex("(\w)(\1){0,}", RegexOptions.Compiled)
Dim sString As String = re.Replace("AABCAABDCEAADAAECDBAACBAA", Function(match) match.Length.ToString() + match.Value(0) + ", ")
Dim sResult As String = sString.Remove(sString.LastIndexOf(","))
Console.WriteLine(sResult)
```

Result =>

```
2A, 1B, 1C, 2A, 1B, 1D, 1C, 1E, 2A, 1D, 2A, 1E, 1C, 1D, 1B, 2A, 1C, 1B, 2A
```